# Best way to Word document files to image and then image to PDF conversion?

Tags: microsoft-word, print-to-pdf, pdfcreator

I want to convert word .docx files containing images text to pure images and then converter that images to PDF files.

Best way i found is send word files to one note, then save one note file as .docx and finally converter this file in PDF.

But any other more convenient way for this?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: Which OS? Apple has this functionality built into their print screen (I think bottom left corner).  On windows, I would look up [Bullzip](http://www.bullzip.com/products/pdf/info.php). Again, it's accessed through the print menu.

Comment: Why first convert it to an image, why not print it to a 'PDF printer'?  There are several of those available for free. (Where 'free' means 'free, but do remove the tick when they ask to install additonal toolsbars'.)

Comment: @Hennes: My guess is he's trying hard to ensure the text is not editable, and directly printing to PDF would defeat his aim (any PDF editing restrictions can be easily removed).

Comment: In that case he might need to look up OCR software. It is getting surprisingly good at recognising 'printed text images'.

Comment: "containing images text" = "containing images *and* text" or "containing images *with* text" (i.e. there is no real text in there, just images containing text)? [Please edit](http://superuser.com/posts/577203/edit)

Answer (score 0):

How about Windows' Snipping Tool? It can capture portions of the screen and save in many formats. Another program called Snagit does the same – but I believe it can save directly to a PDF.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion can handle word file with hundreds or thousands of pages.

Step 1. Print to pdf with word builtin function or 3rt party pdf printer

Step 2. Open the pdf with [Pdfxchange viewer](http://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer), which can export all pages in pdf as jpg, gif, tiff, etc. Use File -> Export.

Step 3. Merge all page again with Freepic2pdf, which I have make a recommendation on this [link](https://superuser.com/questions/202480/trying-to-package-a-directory-of-images-into-a-pdf)

At last, I should say I agree Hennes very much, OCR is very good at recogonizing printed charactors. So this method will cause some trouble, but it can not protect your work too much.